# How do I change css colour variables if an element is scrolled into view?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a website which is just one page with a navbar that uses fragment links to scroll to different sections of the page. I want the navbar to change color when the section it scrolls to appears on the user's screen. Is it possible to do this?

The default colors are in the :root and the colors I want it to change to are in #about at the bottom of the css code.

```css
@import url("https://use.typekit.net/cpb3gji.css");

:root {
  --text: #fff;
  --background: #9A031E;
  --nav-bg: #321325;
  --nav-btn: #CB793A;
  --nav-btn-hov: #FCDC4D;
  --nav-btn-shadow: #5F0F40;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.3s ease all;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: "DINosaur", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: var(--background);
  color: var(--text);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--text) !important;
}

nav {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: var(--nav-bg);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav ul a li {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  --shadow1: var(--nav-btn-shadow);
  --shadow2: #000;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 var(--shadow1), 4px 4px 0 var(--shadow1), 6px 6px 0 var(--shadow1), 8px 8px 0 var(--shadow1);
  background: var(--nav-btn);
}

nav ul a img {
  width: 10rem;
}

nav ul a li:hover {
  background: var(--nav-btn-hov);
  color: #fff !important;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 var(--shadow1), 4px 4px 0 var(--shadow1), 6px 6px 0 var(--shadow1), 8px 8px 0 var(--shadow1), 10px 10px 10px var(--shadow2), 12px 12px 10px var(--shadow2);
  transform: translate(-4px, -4px);
}

nav ul a:nth-of-type(1):hover {
  background: none !important;
}

nav ul a:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-right: 3rem;
}

main section {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  background: var(--accent);
  border-top: solid 3px #000;
  padding: 1rem;
}

main section h1 {
  transform: translateY(-3rem);
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow:
  -1px -1px 0 #000,  
   1px -1px 0 #000,
   -1px 1px 0 #000,
    1px 1px 0 #000;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

main section p {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  text-align: center;
}

main section:nth-of-type(1) .img-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

main section:nth-of-type(1) .img-grid img {
  width: 100%;
}

.back-navigation {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 2rem;
  user-select: none;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  font-family: "amatic-sc", sans-serif;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.back-navigation:hover {
  animation-name: wobble;
}

@keyframes wobble {
  0% {
    rotate: -5deg;
  }
  50% {
    rotate: 5deg;
  }
  100% {
    rotate: -5deg;
  }
}

.splide img {
  width: 100%;
}

main section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.splide {
  width: 60%;
}

#about {
  --text: #000;
  --background: #FFE74C;
  --nav-bg: #FF5964;
  --nav-btn: #35A7FF;
  --nav-btn-hov: #FFFFFF;
  --nav-btn-shadow: #38618C;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <a href="#about"><li>About</li></a>
    <a href="#solution"><li>Our solution</li></a>
    <a href="#how"><li>How it works</li></a>
    <a href="#use"><li>How to use</li></a>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <section id="about">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>
      Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
    </p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Is it possible to achieve this in vanilla js?

Comment: Yes it is. You would likely want to look into [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for detecting when elements have scrolled into view, and you can [set custom properties' values in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#values_in_javascript) similarly to other CSS properties.